# After saving a Content Language it doesn't appear in the list

Tags: language

I have a site and I'm trying to add a second language to it. I've followed the steps outlined here:

[How to setup a new multi-language website?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-to-setup-a-new-multi-language-website)

But when I try to create a content language (Spanish), it won't appear in the content language list, even though it says it has saved successfully. If I try to recreate the same content language it says one already exists.

The issue its causing is that only English(UK) is appearing in language drop downs when I try to create a menu item or module. Is there a way to view the Content Language I've created? And if so, will that add it to the Menu Item languages dropdown?

Comment: Did you installed the Languagepack for this language?

Comment: Yes, "Spanish (ES)" appears under the `Installed - site` and `Installed - administrator` tabs, but not in the content tab

Comment: Did the content language tag is exactly "es-ES" and the access right and status correct?

Comment: yes, exactly "es-ES" and Published. If it helps, I've checked the database and the only row in the __languages table is the English one.

Comment: You found a answer, good maybe you write a comment what your problem solved?

Comment: I may have just have created the Content Language incorrectly, although I don't think I did anything different. I reset my database and tried it again with Spanish and its showing up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most problems configuring a Multilingual Site are caused by an inconsistent configuration. Check these steps:

**How to Create a Multilingual Site in Joomla**
http://www.rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/basic/how_to_create_a_multilingual_site.md

Otherwise, you can just create a new site following the simple steps offered by the installer to create the proper structure.