# Change multi-language admin panel setup

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, custom-component, language, multilingual

I am new to Joomla. I want to create a multi-language website using Joomla CMS. 
I followed the instructions at https://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-configuration-multilanguage-site.html#gref and I succeeded in making a multilingual website, but now I want to modify the Joomla `back-end`.

As i know it, the Joomla back-end needs multiple articles for each language; By that I mean, if we have a page "about-us" for 3 languages then we need to create 3 articles- one article for each language. Am I right?

What i need -

I need to manage all 3 language contents in a single article. That means for the about-us page I'd like to have a single article and all 3 language contents will be manage on this single page and on the frontend the content will be shown according to the selected language.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please check this link, it may help you. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-to-setup-a-new-multi-language-website?rq=1

Comment: try it using gtranslate module https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/gtranslate/

Answer (score 1):

If your content is different language then you need 3 Articles

Example:
Say your 3 Language is English, French and German

1) About Us => Make one for English Language and put English content

2) About Us => Make one for French Language and put French content

3) About Us => Make one for Germany Language and put German content

Then you need to make 3 menus for 3 Language then Joomla will detect auto as language selection the content and menu. Make sure you properly configure multi-language plugin and menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, to each article you define one language or "all languages". In the frontend you will see the article only if the language is accordingly. Eg. frontend selected language is "English", article defined language is "all languages", but written in German and French and English: the article will be shown completely as far as you not use the plugin refeered to in the comment below. I suppose if you put each part of your article between {lang en} and {/lang} than it should work as you wish. But I do not know for which languages this plugin works.

Comment: Edit: I just found a similar question with this anwer, this may work not only for one word but for all the content located between the { } parentheses.

You can use this language plugin:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easy-language

Once installed in your article you can do:

{lang en}Monday{/lang}{lang es}Lunes{/lang}

It will display the text on the selected language.